# Are continuous processes almost surely bounded?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Is any process with continuous sample paths almost surely bounded on a finite horizon? If this is true, let $\{X_t\}_{t \in [0, T]}$ be such a process with continuous sample paths. Then we have $|X_t| \leq K$, a.e. $t \in [0, T]$, a.s.
If this argument is OK, we have ${\mbox E} [|X_t|^p] \leq K^p$, for any $p \in [1,\infty)$. Could we say that any process with continuous sample paths has a finite (bounded) moment up to any order $p \in [1,\infty)$? And we could even claim that any continuous process on a finite horizon is uniformly integrable. This seems ridiculous. Please correct me if there is any flaw.

Comment: By saying $|X_t| \leq K$, you mean that $K$ is a random variable that depends on the process $X_t$, not that $K$ is a given constant.  So $E[|X_t|^p]\leq E[K^p]$.  For example, let $Y$ be any nonnegative random variable and define $X_t=Y$ for all $t$.  Then clearly every sample path of $X_t$ is constant (and hence continuous), but $E[|X_t|^p]$ is finite only when $E[Y^p]$ is finite.

Comment: Couldn't we find a deterministic bound $K$ for $X_t$?

Comment: Can you do it for the example $X_t=Y$ for all $t$?

Comment: No, I can't. The boundedness of continuous processes leads to nothing, as the bound is random. But can we find a almost surely finite bound,i.e., $K < \infty$ a.s.?

Comment: If $S$ is a sample space, a random variable is a function $X:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  So $X(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}$ for all outcomes $\omega \in S$.  So $X(\omega)$ is (surely) finite.  Likewise, if for each $\omega \in S$ we have that $X_t(\omega)$ is a continuous real-valued function over a closed interval $t \in [0, T]$, then $\sup_{t \in [0,T]}|X_t(\omega)|$ exists and is (surely) finite. In fact $\sup_{t \in [0,T]}|X_t(\omega)|$ is itself a random variable (since it is a real-valued function of $\omega$). You can call it $K(\omega)$ if you like.

Comment: @Michael could we say somthing about $\mathbb{E}K$ ?

Comment: @user1 : This is from 2 years ago.  I'm not sure what you are asking.  If $K$ is a nonnegative random variable, can we say something about $E[K]$? It is the expected value of $K$.  It can be finite or infinite.

Comment: @Michael right, but I was referring to the case when it was the sup for a continous process as above. But maybe that donst tell us anything

Comment: @user1 Again you can take the continuous process $X(t) = K$ for all $t$, where $K$ is random.